# cannot import name DjangoServiceBase

Tags: django, spyne

I have a problem. spyne example dosn't work.

```
>>> django.get_version()
'1.6.5'

from spyne.util.django import DjangoComplexModel, DjangoServiceBase
```

ImportError: cannot import name DjangoServiceBase

Comment: which version of `spyne` ? Looks like version `2.11.1` has this class.

Comment: spyne 2.11.0 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyne

Comment: Make sure you're running the right python interpreter that has both Spyne and Django.